# How many subsets of two non-consecutive elements of $\mathbb N^{*}_n$ can be constructed?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let $\mathbb N^{*}_n=\{1,2,...n\}$ be the set of the first $n$ integers greater than zero.
>
> How many subsets of two non-consecutive elements of $\mathbb N^{*}_n$ can be constructed ?

What does two non-consecutive elements mean ? Can we separate it into 2 sets like $\{1,3,5,...\}$ $\{2,4,6,...\}$

Is it then $2^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}+2^{\lceil{n/2}\rceil}$ or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  The subsets have just two elements, so can be represented as $\{a,b\}$.  The restriction says $a \neq b+1, b \neq a+1$.  Start with all two element subsets-how many of these are there?  Now subtract the number where $a,b$ are next to each other.

Comment: $\binom{n}{2}-(n-1)$ ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: also $a\ne b$​​

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide a combinatorical counting argument. Without the non-consecutiveness condition, the answer would be ${n \choose 2} = \frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}$. Intuitively, you choose 1 number first ($n$ choices) and another one from the remaining set ($n-1$ choices) and abstract away the move sequence.

Back to the original problem, for each $m \in \{2, ..., n-1\}$ there are three instead of one number that you cannot choose as the second item, thus you have $\frac{n\cdot(n-3)}{2}$ choices. The analogue argument holds for the border cases $m \in \{1, n\}$ which restrict your choice set in move 2 by 1 giving you $\frac{2\cdot(n-1)}{2}$ choices.

Put together: $N = \frac{n\cdot(n-3)}{2} + \frac{2\cdot(n-1)}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$.